# Measuring goodness of fit/is chi-squared appropriate?

Tags: chi-squared-test, simulation, goodness-of-fit

I'm a physics rather than statistics student so please bear with me...
I've got a simulation which produces some deterministic curves of the area covered by a particular weather system over time. These curves are produced numerically and *aren't* neat functions $A = f(t, [\textrm{params, etc.}])$. I'm comparing this to a single set of historical data for the event I'm considering (which, for argument's sake, *doesn't* have uncertainties given).

In physics, we often test goodness of fit using $\chi^2 = \sum\left [(O_i - E_i) / \sigma_i \right ] ^2$ where $\sigma_i$ is the uncertainty on the experimental data point. I'm also aware of the alternative definition of $\chi^2$ with an $E_i$ on the bottom, but I understand that's usually for testing whether a sample fits a particular distribution.

My question is whether I can use $\chi^2$ at all here considering that I'm not dealing with noisy experimental data, and how I can quantify the goodness of fit of my model without really having uncertainties as we usually do in more experimental physics.